# SQL query for how to display shifts between given start time and end time

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I have a table 'shiftMaster' in that different shift
(eg. 1) 03 AM to 12 PM - Morning shift
     2) 11 AM to 3 PM - Afternoon shift
     3) 2 PM to 8 PM - Evening shift
     4) 8 PM to 5 AM - Night shift )

- I am enter start time and end time
  (e.g 1 PM To 6 AM then it will display 2 shift like
   Evening shift
   Night shift )

How to Write Query for that..?

Comment: You will have to use CASE statement here. Can you provide input data?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the expected output.  Note that storing a shift time without its corresponding is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Tag properly!!! MySQL <> Oracle.  Which one is this???

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like that

```
SELECT * 
  FROM shiftMaster
 WHERE Shift_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 13:00:00') 
                      AND DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 15:00:00');
```